# How to trigger functions on long press volume button in flutter from lock screen

Tags: flutter

I am developing an app in flutter and want to trigger a notification or msg every time a user long press vol button from the lock screen to the contacts which user has given at the time of registration

i tried using method channel class and developing natively for both ios and android but i want to know if there is any inbuilt packages in flutter